# Why does blocksize arguments change for shell utilities on Linux vs OSX?

Tags: linux, macos, dd, gnu, bsd

When following a tutorial for flashing a ROM that uses the *dd* utility, I received an console warning that '1M' was not a supported blocksize.  OSX requires a blocksize of '1m'.  What is the root reason why Linux and OSX have different blocksize arguments?

From man page of *dd* utility:

```
bs=n     Set both input and output block size to n bytes, superseding the ibs and obs operands.  If no
          conversion values other than noerror, notrunc or sync are specified, then each input block is
          copied to the output as a single block without any aggregation of short blocks.
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a [GNU](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Block-size.html) versus [BSD](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dd.1.html) thing, unrelated to the *dd* utility.